# Is the padding property inherited in css

Tags: css

Hey I am currently having the following code :

```css
   .blah {
     padding: 15px;
     background:green;
    }
   .blah div{
     background:red;
    }
```

```html
 <div class='blah'>
     <div>
        foo
     </div>
    </div>
```

Though, foo doesn't seem to have any padding. Does that mean that I have to specifically add `padding: inherit` for the inner div ?

Comment: I hope code is working fine you are getting 15px padding for .foo if u need padding for inner div, you need to give it again http://jsfiddle.net/5vg7mdef/

Comment: If you're asking if children inherit the `padding` of their parents, your own Snippet answers that. If you're asking whether `inherit` is a valid value for `padding`, that's something you could have very easily tested yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value for `padding` properties is `0` (see, e.g., [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/padding)).

Typically, setting `padding` to `inherit` isn't a sensible option: you want to be explicit about which element has which kind of padding.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is first of all incorrect, your closing `</div>` is missing the closing `>` Element. And for your question, yes you have to inherit the property or define the padding for the child element.